# Should I have XP boosters from the DLC's already?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

I just noticed something. I went to the "manage game" page and there was 3 items ready to install that I hadn't installed yet.

One of them was "Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon Wildlands: Dragon Pack".

This item has an icon that shows an "XP Booster" for 2 hours. After downloading this, should I now own one such booster?

I have none of those boosters but now I see that the Peruvian Connection pack should come with one, and a few of the other DLC packs also seems to indicate they should come with one.

Basically, given that I bought the biggest and baddest package on Xbox One, and have downloaded and installed everything, should I have one or more of those XP boosters? Because if I should, then I need to contact support and ask for help since I have none.

I just saw that the item has a description text as well:

> Get the exclusive "Dragon" gear patch to wear while you explore the Wildlands and **unlock a 2 hour XP Booster to help you increase the amount of XP earned in the game.**

So the question now probably is this: Did I get an automatic 2 hour XP boost, or should I have gotten one of those booster items I can opt to activate myself?

Comment: Looking through the bundle, you should have a few.  Are you positive you don't have any?

Comment: Yes, positive. I've checked both the store screen, which should list xp boosts as "owned (x)" if I had any, as well as the booster activation screen, which shows none. I have created a support ticket as I seem to be missing a lot from my gold edition / season pass. Judging by the forums I appear to be in good company.

Answer (score 1):

I only have GR:Wildlands with gold & season pass (i.e. everything available on the DLC & season pass menu). My boosters show I have 6 2-hr boosters (in-game: go to menu then store->boosters, if you have all the DLC then you should have this too).
So yes, check and if there's nothing there, something is wrong.